# Understanding debugtrace log of postgresql installer binary

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.6 on a CentOS 7.6 VM using installer binary postgresql-9.6.6-1-linux-x64.run. I have run the below command to install:

```
./postgresql-9.6.6-1-linux-x64.run --installer-language en --serviceaccount postgres --servicename postgresqld  --datadir "/home/postgres/" --prefix  "/home/postgres" --superpassword **** --serverport 5432 --debuglevel 4 --debugtrace ./postgresql-debug.log --mode unattended
```

The debug trace log "./postgresql-debug.log" generated lot of encoded formatted text which cannot be understood.

It is not in base64 either. Can someone please help me how to decode the log.

Here is first few lines of debug trace log.

```
<errorDump>
    <context>MwSUdmn65MlwA81MDBVmg34ZjlXDReCYnIxjAwgZ15jHp8UXS0OQ2L/a8iph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```

Comment: Why don't you install it through the official RPMs?

Comment: Our installation process is automated process through a script. The script reads set of inputs chosen by client (install path, port number, user name, password, etc....) and builds the installer command.